# how to manually uninstall node , npm and angular cli completely globally n locally

Tags: angularjs, node.js

On my Windows 7 machine, I'm unable to update/uninstall an existing global angular-cli instance following the approach outlined here https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

using these following commands

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

i tried to uninstall angular cli then nodejs and afterwards  installed latest nodejs and angular cli.
then after when i run ng -v i get errors. so i want to manually uninstall node , npm and angular cli globally and locally completely so that i can install fresh copy.

Comment: Please, provide the error you are getting when following those steps. I have tried them on two machines (Windows 10 and Windows 7) and they worked without problems.

Comment: i deleted some files and re-installed nodejs. Now,from command line, i can see                                                                                                            
     <pre>Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Hp-pc>node -v
v6.10.3

C:\Users\Hp-pc>npm -v
3.10.10

C:\Users\Hp-pc>ng -v
   
   @angular/cli: 1.1.0
node: 6.10.3
os: win32 x64

C:\Users\Hp-pc></pre>

Comment: but using git-bash : 
Hp-pc@Hp MINGW64 ~/Desktop/New
$ ng -v
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module '../models/config'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)

Comment: at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Hp-pc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\bin\ng:7:46)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)